# Java path set wrongly

Tags: java, windows, windows-8

I have installed Java on a new system. Some random path in my C drive is automatically set for my `PATH` variable. Whenever I try to run Java, it shows `java.exe not found` in that wrong path!

I'm trying to change the `PATH` variable using the `SET` command, but the new path is only getting added along with the old one. I could not run Java on the system.

```
set PATH=%PATH%;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_71\bin
```

I've tried setting `PATH` variable in Windows Environment Variables list also after setting `JAVA_HOME`!

When I type Java in `cmd`, i get:

> The system cannot find the file C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath\java.exe.

This path is the old unknown automatically set path.

Is there any way to run Java! I'm using windows 8.

Comment: You're in windows - don't use the command line for this, just change the path in the system settings either for yourself or globally, but going to the control panel -> system -> advanced settings -> environment variables. Modify the PATH variable's content the normal way (paths, separated by the `;` character)

Comment: If I am not mistaken (I never need to use this command so it would be nice if someone could confirm or deny it) it will only set temporary path value (which can be useful in `.bat` files) but after console will be closed (or after batch will end) original value or path will be restored. Try maybe going to system properties and set `path` there manually.

Comment: Anyway maybe this will help you a little https://www.java.com/en/download/help/path.xml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you are using windows system, please create java_home as a variable and set java home path i.e. till `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_71`, and in path variable do not delete existing just append new with `;%java_home%\bin`

this will work

in you case SET is valid till command prompt is open. 
do the above changes in my computer -> properties -> advanced ->environment variables

Comment: stil having the problem..
The system cannot find the file C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath\java.exe(which s the old unknown path) when i type java in cmd! javac works fine

Comment: this is not installation path of java

Comment: you are contradicting yourself - at first you said java doesnt work and now it all of a sudden it works fine.

Comment: if i type javac, it s showing the options along with i can use javac.. but on typing java, cmd says the above error where the path doesnt exist at all!

Comment: your java got corrupted - you need to uninstall every version of java and install via the official installer : http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html. You dont need to set your path manually - whoever told you to do so : dont believe him again. Ever.

Answer (score 1):

I know this post id very old. I faced this issue recently. Please follow the  following steps to resolve your issue:

1. Search for "Regedit" in "start menu".
2. Once found, right-click it and choose "run as Administrator" option.
3. Enter your administrator credentials and Enter.
4. Go to "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment\1.7"
5. Double-click on "JavaHome" name and change its value to "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_71".
6. Close all your command prompts and open a new Command prompt and it should reflect.

Answer (score -3):

```
set PATH=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_71\bin;
```

will set the path of java only
    and the old path will not get added and that will be till the command prompt
    session lasts.

to keep the existing path setting intact and add the java path use below command.

```
set PATH=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_71\bin;%PATH%
```

Comment: This also removes everything else from this user session %PATH%

Comment: @SimplyInk I have already specified "will set the path of java only and the old path will not get added"

Comment: Added more information, I feel the user should retain their path variables so they can still use the other programs set in their path. Also, I suspect the solution to the poster's problem was he needed to remove the existing "C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath\java.exe." from his path. An uninstall + install of JRE may fix this too as the symlink is recreated.